# Different cursorline for netrw and regular files

Tags: vim

I want my `cursorline` to be different when I'm in `netrw` (want it to appear more prominent) and in regular files (less prominent).

I tried

```
 if &ft ==# "netrw"
      :hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=green ctermfg=black
 else
      :hi CursorLine ctermbg=233 ctermfg=NONE cterm=NONE guibg=#303030 guifg=NONE gui=NONE
 endif
```

, but only the part after `else` works (both in regular files and in `netrw`). I checked that when I'm in `netrw`, the `filetype` is indeed set to `netrw`. What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Since `CursorLine` isn't buffer-specific maybe a `BufEnter` autocmd to run your code block would be sufficient.

Comment: @RandyMorris if netrw actually sets the filetype, you could use an ftplugin.